# Can I connect VM to a VPN and still have the host with my usual Internet conection?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn

I know I can connect my VM to a VPN and don’t connect my host to the same VPN. My question is, if I do that, is it possible to hide that your VM is running on the host? Basically, can I hide from the rest of the Internet that there is any relation between the two machines?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are doing on the internet and what is collected there could be a lot of factors here.

If you are just visiting a website you should be pretty much set as it's going to gather information about the VM's browser and most importantly the public IP from the VPN.

Using a VPN client that will prevent DNS leaks, and ideally a firewall to prevent other leaks will further increase security.

Information about the host really isn't going to be gathered even by applications that are sending diagnostic information (such as usage statistics in browser) will provide some information that you are using a VM but not information about the host.

See this guide for tons of info on how you could set up an extremely anonymous setup:

https://www.ivpn.net/privacy-guides/advanced-privacy-and-anonymity-part-1

Disclaimer: Sites can gather lots of information these days so depending on the level of security needed there could be a lot of factors to consider (such as VM OS, type of VPN etc.)

Comment: Yes Of course the ISP can see data going both from this home PC, to 1)VPN company x, 2) other internet traffic not inside the VPN.  What the user's ISP can't see is what the data inside the VPN contains other that general info like size, rate, ... which can give clues.    Browser Fingerprinting is an issue, the Tor Browser running at a common screen resolution is recommended.